# Search query builder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, search, builder

There are 8 columns in an HTML table and the user has the option to search with any of the 8 columns through a search field.

I want to avoid searching against multiple columns in one or more tables.

I want to determine the probable column the search value is in based on the characters entered in the search field.

I will then pass the search value and the the probable column name to my server side component to search for the values in database.

**Question**

How to handle this and any pre-built libraries available towards this?

Comment: Provide your tries and code here for more details.

Comment: Hi addy, I have not started coding for it yet and it is basically a design level query based on which I need to do development. I will update once I start working on it with the actual sample code.